# Google Sheet merged cells create space

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, cellspacing

I got a sheet with merged cells and in those merged cells, a script write its results.

When I copy this result in the merged cells, it gave me multiple spaces at the end. 
Like : `Result #1________` (« _ » represent invisible space)

When I put the same result in a normal cell (not merged), it doesn’t put any space at the end. 
`Result #1`

I tried multiple cell format (Center aligned, left aligned, etc.) but nothing changed.

Do you have any idea why ?

Thanks !

**EDIT : add script**

Script

```
function Devise() {
  const sheetName = "Missions";
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var Devise = "";
  var NombreMission = "";
  var NomOperateurs = "";

  if(sheet.getRange("H2").getValue()=="") { // Si la mission 7 est vide
    NombreMission = 6; // On compte seulement 6 missions
  } else {
    NombreMission = 7; // Sinon on compte 7 missions
  }


  for (i = 1; i < NombreMission+1; i++) {    // Boucle FOR pour NombreMission missions
    if(sheet.getRange(2,i+1).getValue()=="") { continue; } // Si la mission est vide, on la passe
    Devise = Devise + i + "/";
    l = 0;    // Variable pour indiquer "Rien" si personne à placer dans la mission
    NomOperateurs = ""; // Reset les noms pour la mission d'après

    for (j = 1; j < 27+1; j++) {   // Boucle FOR pour tous les opérateurs
      if(sheet.getRange(j+2,i+1).getFontWeight() == 'bold') {     // Vérifie si la case est en gras

        /*if(i!=NombreMission) {  // Tant qu'il ne s'agit pas de la dernière mission ...
          Devise = Devise + sheet.getRange(j+2,1).getValue() + " "; // ... on affiche les opérateurs
        }*/

        NomOperateurs = NomOperateurs + sheet.getRange(j+2,1).getValue() + " ";
        l = l + 1;  // On compte les opérateurs
      }
    }  // Fin Boucle FOR opérateurs

    if (l==24) {                              // S'il y a tous les operateurs sur une mission...
      Devise = Devise + "ALL OPs! "            // ... On affiche "All Op!"
    } else if (i==NombreMission && l!=0) {    // Sinon s'il s'agit de la dernière mission et qu'il reste des opérateurs à placer...
      Devise = Devise + "Autres + Epic ";     // ... On indique qu'il s'agit du reste et des épiques
    } else if (l==0) {                        // Sinon s'il n'y a aucun opérateurs à placer...
      Devise = Devise + "RIEN "               // ... On indique "RIEN"
    } else {                                  // Sinon ... 
      Devise = Devise + NomOperateurs;        // ... On affiche les opérateurs
    }



  }  // FIN BOUCLE FOR NombreMission
  if(NombreMission==6 && Devise!="") { Devise = Devise + "7/!NOTHING!";}
  sheet.getRange("K13").setValue(Devise);
}
```

Comment: Which script are you using? Would you mind posting the code to it as well? @Saku

Comment: @ale13 alright I just edit my post but the script doesn’t change anything because when I change the merged cell (K13) to a normal cell, I don’t have the space. So I guess the script is not the problem

Comment: When you set the value for the `K13` cell, you are using the `Devise` value. But your `Devise` variable is composed of `"Devise + text_with_space_after_it"`. Is this what you are referring to? If not, how do you merge cells? And which cells? @Saku

Comment: No the Devise variable doesn’t have space after but only when I copy the value of K13 it add multiple spaces as I said. 
But in an another cell, there is no space after. 

K13 is merged as K13:M15

Comment: I tried to replicate what you mentioned but I was unable to do so. Do you have any screenshots of the actual behavior and how you would like it to look like?

Comment: Screen #1 : https://prnt.sc/syhk20 this is the screen from merged cells that give this output `4/Hawk Joe Capisce 5/Boris Rick Mishka Klaus Batya 6/Autres + Epic 7/!NOTHING!________________` (« _ » represent space that StackOverflow is hiding)  Screen #2 : https://prnt.sc/syhlg6 from a normal cell this give this output : `4/Hawk Joe Capisce 5/Boris Rick Mishka Klaus Batya 6/Autres + Epic 7/!NOTHING!`

Comment: Do you this option [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgMX5.png) checked on the merge cells?

Comment: Yes it is checked but I just tried them all and it’s still the same problem with those three option

Comment: Can you replicate the same behavior you have mentioned but with other cells from another sheet/spreadsheet?

Comment: @ale13 Yes I just tried on another spreadsheet, I merged some cells and input some text and even if I just write some text directly from keyboard, it does the space thing when I copy - paste

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to the **data you copied** and **the way that you copied** it as pasting text in merged cells doesn't create any new lines.

Also, an important thing to keep in mind is that `CTRL+ENTER` creates the mentioned space also known as a ***line break***.

So, for example, if this cell contains the text `Text + line break`:

[image: cell with text with line break]

And the text from the above cell is copied and pasted into a *merged cell* it will look like this - which is the same outcome as the one that you have mentioned:

[image: merged cell with text with line break]

But if you paste the same text to a *simple cell*, it will look like this:

[image: cell with text in it]

This is essentially because the **line break** will signify the start of a new cell.

For example, this cell contains this text with line breaks:

[image: ![cell with text with multiple line breaks]

After the text is copied and pasted into a different cell, this is how it will actually be pasted as:

[image: text with multiple line breaks in cells]

In order to solve your issue, I suggest you to *copy only the text needed* and if possible to *avoid using any line breaks*.

#### Reference

- [Edit and Format a Spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/46973?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Comment: But I don’t use line breaks, I select my merged cell and hit CTRL C, I don’t actually copy the text in it. 
But, if I copy the text in the formula area, it has no space after. 
Also when I double click in the cell, like to edit it, there’s no space left after, and also if I copy the text, there’s no space after either.  In fact, it causes this only if I copy the cell and not actually the text

Comment: It seems then that the issue is related to your formatting as coying a cell in merged cells does not create any space after it either.

Comment: Check here on a fresh new spreadsheet the same problem : https://imgur.com/a/2qN3G5E

Comment: Maybe in this situation you can report this to **Help**->**Report a problem** from the Sheets app.

Answer (score 0):

Encountering the same issue.
I have a merged cell with text. If I select the cell and paste it into notepad, It includes quite a lot of white space.
I've checked and if the merged cell spans two rows, the white space includes a line break.
If the merged cell spans one row but two columns, the white space does not include a line break.

If I have a single cell and have it take its value from the mered cell "=A1", the text does not include the white space.

So the addition of the whitespace is definitely the result of having a merged cell.